# Tool to generate two bell shape curves for given means and standard deviations

Tags: graphs, statistics

I want to generate a a couple of bell shaped curves for demonstrative purposes.

[image: hand drawn example of two bell curves]

The curves aren't calculated on real data; I should be able to specify a standard deviation and mean for each colour, and it draws it nicely for me.

Is there either an online tool or simple tool or library that will do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [python](http://python.org) using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) you can do this quite easily, the following is one of the examples:

```
"""
Demo of the histogram (hist) function with a few features.

In addition to the basic histogram, this demo shows a few optional features:

    * Setting the number of data bins
    * The ``normed`` flag, which normalizes bin heights so that the integral of
      the histogram is 1. The resulting histogram is a probability density.
    * Setting the face color of the bars
    * Setting the opacity (alpha value).

"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# example data
mu = 100  # mean of distribution
sigma = 15  # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

num_bins = 50
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
# add a 'best fit' line
y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--')
plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.title(r'Histogram of IQ: $\mu=100$, $\sigma=15$')

# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of ylabel
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.show()
```

If you simply have 2 values for mu & sigma, (or prompt for them), leave out the labels and title, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_bins = 50
for mu, sigma, col, line in [(120, 15, 'red', 'r-'), (80,20, 'green', 'g-')]:
    x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor=col, alpha=0.01)
    y = mlab.normpdf(bins, mu, sigma)
    plt.plot(bins, y, line)
plt.show()
```

I got a window with the display but with lots of export possibilities such as the jpeg below.

[image: My Plot]

I am sure that you can improve on my code, etc.

All the tools mentioned and used are:

- Free Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform working on Windows, OS-X & Linux plus others.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable solution :)